# Javascript files getting included multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

For some reason my javascript files are getting included in my source 12 times.  Other members of my team, using the same source, do not have this problem.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you are precompiling all of your assets?

Try using:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: I don't want to precompile in development mode do I?  I'd like to be able to debug in chrome without dealing with a compressed file.

Comment: As long as it's precompiled in production mode you shouldn't run into the same issue, I think there's something in the development.rb that deals with this but can't remember off the top of my head.